# Notice: Undefined index: NAME in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\lib\config.php on line 108

Tags: php

I have debugging an little open source php script and have found this error message could someone please give me some explanation what is wrong with it?

Many thanks in advance

here is the bit which is mentioned:

```
function HNDCData($parser,$cdata) {
        $cdata = str_replace("[amp]","&",$cdata);
        //echo "<br>" . $cdata;
        // create the proper tree node if NAME attribute is set
        if ($this->attr["NAME"] != "")
            $this->tags[count($this->tags) - 1] = $this->attr["NAME"];
```

and the full php file:

```
   <?php

    class CConfig extends CXMLParser {
        /**
        * current depth in xml tree
        *
        * @var int
        *
        * @access private
        */
        var $depth = 0;

        /**
        * depth tags parser helper
        *
        * @var array
        *
        * @access private
        */
        var $tags = array();

        /**
        * config tree
        *
        * @var array
        *
        * @access public
        */
        var $vars = array();

        /**
        * creates the xml parser and optionally loads a config file
        *
        * @param string $file_name  config file name to load
        *
        * @return void
        *
        * @access public
        */
        function CConfig($file_name = "") {
            parent::CXMLParser();

            if ($file_name != "")
                $this->Load($file_name);
        }

        /**
        * xml parser open tag handler
        *
        * @param object $parser actual expat parser
        * @param string $tag    current xml tag
        * @param array $attr    current tag attributes
        *
        * @return void
        *
        * @acces private
        */
        function HNDTagOpen($parser,$tag,$attr) {//echo "<pre>";
            // call parent to save tag and attr info for cdata handler
            parent::HNDTagOpen($parser,$tag,$attr);

            // expand helper tag array
            $this->tags[$this->depth] = $tag;
            $this->depth++;

            // prepare dynamic code for attr handling
            foreach ($this->tags as $key => $val)
                $code[] = "\"" . strtolower($val) . "\"";

            // build code
            $node = implode("][",$code);
            $code = "foreach (\$attr as \$key => \$val) if (\$key != \"NAME\") \$this->vars[$node][strtolower(\$key)] = \"\$val\"; else \$this->vars[\$attr[\"NAME\"]][strtolower(\"\$key\")] = \"\$val\";";

            // and finally execute
            eval($code);
        }

        /**
        * close tag handler
        *
        * @param object $parser actual expat parser
        * @param string $tag    current xml tag
        *
        * @return void
        *
        * @access private
        */
        function HNDTagClose($parser,$tag) {
            // compress helper tag array
            unset($this->tags[$this->depth]);
            $this->depth--;
        }

        /**
        * character data handler
        *
        * @param object $parser actual expat parser
        * @param string $cdata  current tag character data
        *
        * @return void
        *
        * @access private
        */
        function HNDCData($parser,$cdata) {
            $cdata = str_replace("[amp]","&",$cdata);
            //echo "<br>" . $cdata;
            // create the proper tree node if NAME attribute is set
            if ($this->attr["NAME"] != "")
                $this->tags[count($this->tags) - 1] = $this->attr["NAME"];

            // cleanup cdata
            $cdata = trim($cdata);
            //$cdata = preg_replace("/(\015\012)|(\015)|(\012)/","",$cdata);

            // only parse if cdata not void
            if ($cdata != "") {
                //print_r($this->attr);
                //echo "<br>" . $cdata;

                // prepare dynamic code
                foreach ($this->tags as $key => $val)
                    $code[] = "\"" . strtolower($val) . "\"";

                // build code
                $code = "\$this->vars[" . implode("][",$code) . "] = \"" . $cdata . "\";";

                // and finally execute
                eval($code);
            }
        }

        /**
        * load the config file and parse it
        *
        * @param string $file_name  config filename to load
        *
        * @return void
        *
        * @acces public
        */
        function Load($file_name) {
            parent::Parse($this->data = str_replace("&","[amp]",GetFileContents($file_name)));
            $this->vars = ArrayReplace("[amp]" , "&" , $this->vars );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$this->attr` doesn't have a `"NAME"` property.

Comment: you can try to find where the variable attr is defined. you may find it in the parent class CXMLParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if ($this->attr["NAME"] != "")
```

To:

```
if ( isset( $this->attr["NAME"] ) && $this->attr["NAME"] != "")
```